# using jupyter notebook in pycharm - no such notebook dir

Tags: pycharm, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to use jupyter notebook from PyCharm 2016.1. I open a previously created iPython notebook, click in a cell with code, and run it. I get prompted to start jupyter notebook at the default url and click OK. Here are the error messages from the Run window:

```
[C 13:04:23.979 NotebookApp] Bad config encountered during initialization:
The Jupyter HTML Notebook.
[C 13:04:23.979 NotebookApp] No such notebook dir: 'C:\\Users\\cb4\\Documents\\python'
```

iPython Notebook is enabled in PyCharm with the default url.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Jupyter keeps configuration info in the `jupyter_notebook_config.py` file. You can find it in `C:\Users\<user>\.jupyter` on Windows or `~\.jupyter` on linux. Modify the `c.NotebookApp.notebook_dir` entry to the location where you keep your notebooks. You can also use the command line to set it:

```
jupyter-notebook --notebook-dir=<path>
```

Enclose the `<path>` in double quotes on Windows if there is a space in the path name.

If you had iPython installed before upgrading to jupyter, then the [jupyter migration process](http://jupyter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/migrating.html?highlight=notebook_dir) used the settings from your old iPython config file. Maybe it's been a long time since you modified iPython and that is why you are seeing unexpected startup or running behavior from jupyter.

Also, this jupyter command may help troubleshoot directory/path problems:

```
jupyter --paths
```

Comment: Occasionally the `--notebook-dir option` will fail if the config file is wrong, which is why Simon Brunner's answer is also useful.  If you're in a hurry and don't want to bother fixing the config file, you can `cd` to the directory you want and start jupyter notebook without the notebook-dir option.

Answer (score 5):

Just had the same problem and resolved it with the following command:

```
jupyter notebook --generate-config
```

More infos are here: http://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config.html

It prompted me to replace my current config with the default config. Thus, if you're fine getting rid of your current config, this is an easy option.

Answer (score -2):

I solved this issue by using command prompt in windows :

opening cmd as admin

type in :

```
jupyter notebook --config=/home/john/mystuff/jupyter_notebook_config.json
```

Note that:
before running above script make sure , Anaconda and Jupyter Lab must be *uninstalled*

- Delete all files in C:/ drive
- Then install re-install the latest Python3 , and add/set the Environment path correctly , and isuggested make Pyhon in the main root folder of as C:/Python not c:/User/.../Python , however u need to install Jupyter notebook usin : pip install Jupyter notebook **sometimes u need to install get-pip.py in order to use pip
- There is sometimes that the jupyter_notebook_config.py is missing To create a jupyter_notebook_config.py file, after installing the python ,
- you can use the following command line:

`jupyter notebook --generate-config`